# Аналог mysql_fetch_array для БД sqLite

Tags: phonegap, javascript

Можно ли на `javaScript` как в `php` отобрать всю строку в переменную и потом манипулировать?

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Смотрите пример [PhoneGap Documentation: SQLResultSetList](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#SQLResultSetList).

Comment: да. но он определяет только некоторый элемент массива. н-р: 
results.rows.item(i).id 

Т.е. можно поместить results.rows.item(i) в переменную, а затем запросить элемент?
Н-р: var a = results.rows.item(i)
alert(a.id); ?

Comment: угу. проще попробовать было уже, не?